# Grafana: How to login using auth proxy

Tags: authentication, proxy, grafana

I'm trying to login to grafana using auth proxy.

I created a user using the following api call: `http://localhost:3000/api/user` with the following body

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"",
   "login":"somename",
   "email":"somename",
   "orgId":1,
   "isGrafanaAdmin":false
}
```

and with header: `X-WEBAUTH-USER: somename`

the user is created successfully and I can see it in grafana users, but how can I login as this user?, is there an api that i can call to log me in? I'm confused here.

Answer (score 1):

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/auth-proxy/

> You can configure Grafana to let a HTTP reverse proxy handle authentication.

=> HTTP reverse proxy in front of Grafana is responsible for authentication, not a Grafana. Grafana will only use user identity from the request header. So if you send `X-WEBAUTH-USER: admin`, then request will have `admin` user identity in the Grafana. You will be responsible to configure authentication on the proxy side, which fit your needs (basic auth, OIDC/SAML auth, ...).

Comment: So I want to create a simple external login page that redirects me to grafana after entering email and password, no database or authentication or anything, just a POC. can you point me to a guide where I can create a reverse proxy that hosts the simple login page and redirects to grafana as this user